# Adding a hyperlink inside a paragraph of text in Access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to set up access so I can include a paragraph similar to the one I have right here. In otherwords, I want to be able to have both plain text and an embedded [hyperlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink). I'd also be able to use a text alias for the hyperlink as we see above instead of using " https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink ". I've seen how to make a field a Hyperlink field, but that doesnt allow me to include plain text very well and only allows one hyperlink. This field is recording quality assurance review information and I want to be able to link people back to places in the policy manual.

I've tried copying in a already formatted hyperlink I created in word, but although it formats like a hyperlink the address information is lost. Using the full address on a rich text field works, but some of my hyperlinks are hundreds of char long and thats unwieldy.

Does anyone know a way to embed a basic aliased hyperlink in an access long text field?

Answer (score 0):

A database is not always the best tool for the job. In your case, you might be better off writing your review in an external document, like Word, and then using the attachment field to attach that review to the DB.

Create a new field for your quality assurance review and set the type to attachment:

> On the Datasheet tab, in the Data Type & Formatting group,click the down arrow next to Data Type, and then click Attachment.

For more information please read the official documentation:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/attach-files-and-graphics-to-the-records-in-your-database-d40a09ad-a753-4a14-9161-7f15baad6dbd

Comment: Unfortunately the QA review is the entire reason for the database, and includes dozens of fields. The comment field is the primary piece of info for the staff and they have to review 10 a month. Also, adding tens of thousands of word documents each year would cause too much bloat in the size of the database I would think.  If a non aliased hyperlink works, I'm thinking there must be a way to use one with an alias.

Comment: Try to break that comment field down in to parts. It just smells like bad database design to me. Hard to tell without all the information. You can have a dynamic number of links by making a link table that uses the ReviewID. Then you can have a navigation section that displays all links that contain the current ReviewID, with a description of what the link is.

Comment: Thats a good workaround. Its crazy to me that a Microsoft product cant figure out hyperlinks. It allows rich text, this seems like it should be easy.